# Selenium Firefox 57 failed to connect to binary / localhost

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, build.gradle, geckodriver

I am using Firefox 57, geckodriver 0.19.1 and selenium 3.8.0.
(Java gradle project)
Btw: Chrome is doing fine. My test works.

Firefox starts, but nothing happend. After two or three seconds Intellij shows an exception.

**I know that this could be a possible duplicate, but I can't find any resource, which display the compatible version of each "combination".**

This is my Exception output:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
[...]
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
    at com.bilsteingroup.css.pf2.seleniumtests.ConfigTests.<init>(ConfigTests.java:43)
    at com.bilsteingroup.css.pf2.seleniumtests.ConfigTests.Start(ConfigTests.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

aswell:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows:
[...]
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
    at com.bilsteingroup.css.pf2.seleniumtests.ConfigTests.<init>(ConfigTests.java:43)
    at com.bilsteingroup.css.pf2.seleniumtests.ConfigTests.Start(ConfigTests.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

This is my TestClass:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ConfigTests {

    enum Browser { CHROME, FIREFOX, IE }

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    public ConfigTests() {}

    private ConfigTests(Browser browser) throws URISyntaxException {
        URL chromeURL = getClass().getResource("../../../../../../resources/driver/win/chromedriver_32.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Paths.get(chromeURL.toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath());

        URL firefoxURL = getClass().getResource("../../../../../../resources/driver/win/geckodriver_32_v0-19-1.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Paths.get(firefoxURL.toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath());

        /*URL ieURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("driver" + File.separator + "IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Paths.get(ieURL.toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath());*/

        switch (browser) {
            case CHROME:
                webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case FIREFOX:
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                /*webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
                webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/
                break;
            case IE:
                webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
        }
    }


    private void goToLocalPartsfinder() {
        webDriver.get("http://localhost:8080");
        WebElement searchFieldElement = webDriver.findElement(By.id("search-input-field"));
        searchFieldElement.sendKeys("08900");
        searchFieldElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    }


    private void quit() {
        webDriver.quit();
    }


    @Test
    public void Start() throws URISyntaxException {

        // Test for each browser definition
        for (Browser browser : Browser.values()) {
            ConfigTests configTests = new ConfigTests(browser);
            configTests.goToLocalPartsfinder();
            configTests.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone give me a hint?
I already used other geckodriver and selenium versions. I am not allowed to change the FF version because of IT restrictions...

I also tried a bunch of FirefoxOptions without any success.

I wonder why chrome is working fine, but firefox is doing nothing.

UPDATE:

```
//build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.8.0'
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.8.0"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.8.0"
}
```

UPDATE2:

After changing the build.gradle to add driver dependencies, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at com.bilsteingroup.css.pf2.seleniumtests.ConfigTests.<init>(ConfigTests.java:38)
    at com.bilsteingroup.css.pf2.seleniumtests.ConfigTests.Start(ConfigTests.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

So I guess that there is still a dependency missing, isnt it?

Comment: Does it work with selenium `3.7.1` or `3.5`?

Comment: I tried 3.7.1 and it didnt. I can also check 3.5.

Comment: There is no `FirefoxDriver` class at 3.5 therefore I dont know how to use it. Any hints?

Comment: `FirefoxDriver` exists since 2.0.
But if it does not work with 3.7.1 then we have to look at another approach.

Comment: Is there a gradle dependency mistake? I'll update my Question to show my build.gradle file

Comment: Oh, you are missing dependencies

Comment: You should add `selenium-firefox-driver` to you dependencies.

And you said you are using selenium 3.8 but there is 3.6 version in your dependencies...

Comment: I updated my Question. I tried 3.6.0 some minutes ago and forget to change it before copying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160284/discussion-between-rafal-laskowski-and-ismoh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by missing dependecies

Download all related Selenium dependencies.

```
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.8.0' 
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.8.0' 
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.8.0' 
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.8.0' 
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.8.0' 
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.8.0' 
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.8.0' 
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.8.0'
```

Comment: Thank you Rafał Laskowski. You helped me a lot!